# visual studio bug or c++ standard changed?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019, c++20

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct base {
    void hello() {
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct ttt : public base<ttt<T>> {
public:
    ttt() {
        hello();
    }
};

int main() {
    ttt<int> t();
    return 0;
}
```

when i use c++ 17 or 11, this code is just ok. but when i set the c++ standard to 20, the C3816 error occurred says can not find hello function, i am confused about the reason, why this error comes until c++ 20.

Comment: development environment : windows visual studio enterprise 2019 preview(16.10.0 preview 3.0)

Comment: The code should not compile. Accepting this code is a bug/misfeature of MSVC that is now fixed under `/std:c++latest`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/permissive-standards-conformance?view=msvc-160#look-up-members-in-dependent-base

Comment: thanks for your explanation,  it is hard to accept that my code has been wrongING so far.

Comment: This code might compile with "permissive" enabled. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/permissive-standards-conformance?view=msvc-160

Comment: To compile the code do : `base<ttt<T>>::hello();`

Comment: PS: it's an obvious attempt to use CRTP, didn't example of such contain proper syntax, or you stumbled on the solution yourself? Fun things like that happens, I saw someone re-inventing CRTP before.

Comment: @degawong, by the way, even solving that, you still have the most vexing parse, if you try `t.hello()`, because `ttt<int> t();` is interpreted as a function declaration. It should be `ttt<int> t{};` instead.

Comment: @Enlico good catch. That also was a MSVC flaw, it sometimes swallowed those

Answer (score 6):

The `hello();` statement isn't dependent on template argument and there is no such name in immediate search context (ie. inside of `ttt` or its non-template base class if any), so name look up would be done in non-template context. I.e. if you had a global function named `hello`, it will be chosen instead. This is dictated by every standard, at least since C++11. A standard compliant way to do that is to make prvalue dependant on  argument of template:

```
     this->hello();  // this is dependant on T
```

Another way is use of a fully qualified name using `base<ttt<T>>::` prefix, but that implies that only that version of function can be chosen. If `ttt` will override it, if inheritance tree will expand and there will be another overload\override of `hello`, if a multiple virtual inheritance will be present, such qualified name might be pointing at unintended function member.

The bug in Visual Studio goes back as far as VS2010 at least,  I personally suffered from it for years because developers would write code that compiles using MSVC bu wouldn't be compiled by gcc and I had to explain them what's wrong, every time ("But it compiles!").

Comment: I would call it non confirming behavior instead of bug. I don't understand, why it can't be the standard for everybody.

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk you're right about what to call it, of course. But being undeclared, it leads to appearance of some hidden bugs in compiled code, there could opposite situation, where we actually intend to call a global or just a non-template function, refer a global variable, etc. VS was breaking it, creating incorrectly working code. This could cause un-debuggable mess in systems with complex hierarchy.

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk: The standard behavior is **superior** in that it avoids having a function call that looks like a call to a free function actually call a member function (or else changing the normal shadowing rules if you prefer the free function).  Failing to implement that was definitely a bug (if an understandable one given the vintage of the compiler).

Comment: Well, they have that bug since VS2005 (and I think, they didn't have it in v6, at least I don't recall it) and it's still going on. Sounds more like they ignore that.

Answer (score 1):

This is a change of default settings.

> Starting in Visual Studio 2019 version 16.8, the /std:c++latest option implicitly sets the /permissive- option.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/permissive-standards-conformance?view=msvc-160

To fix the code prefix the function name with the base class name:

```
base<ttt<T>>::hello();
```

At the top of my class I like to add :

```
using Base = base<ttt<T>>;
```

Then I can call :

```
Base::hello();
```

Comment: in some cases `base<ttt<T>>::hello();` might be too specific, if that function was overridden or shielded by another inside of inheritance chain.

Comment: The key is to use `::` which makes it a dependent name. So can just refer to the current class: `ttt::hello();`.

Comment: @rustyx But `ttt::hello()` isn't correct if `hello()` is virtual, as it won't dispatch virtually.  That's why @Swift's answer of `this->hello()` is the correct one.

Comment: @Ry-Fi In the question, it is not virtual. So it will work for this specific case.

Comment: It got some more hidden issues with that, because it's CRTP. Also you can specialize template for `ttt` after declaring `base` and  suddenly it will become virtual.